# Static function return UIView encounters SIGBART error (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing problem of creating a static function of a class

I am developing an app that requires custom input view. My thinking is to put this function as a go-to, so that whatever type of UIKit components that need this custom input view can just call this function

here is my code

```
class Helper { 
    static func getCustomKeyboard() -> CustomInputView {
       let inputView = UINib(nibName: "CustomInputView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! CustomInputView
       return inputView
    }
}
```

When I call this function in another UIViewController, UIView, or UITableViewCell, the SIGBART error will come out.

However, if I call the following code directly from it is own VC or UIView, there is no error comes out.

```
let inputView = UINib(nibName: "CustomInputView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! CustomInputView
```

What I am doing is now create each UIKit component extensions. This way, the error also won't come out.

So my problem is, Is there any way for me to create a helper function, which is only one, and can be called from anywhere without the SIGBART error?

Thanks

Comment: Please copy and paste the full error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you pass "self" as the owner to the "instantiate" method. In the static method "self" is the Helper class itself.
Try passing "nil" as the owner, or if you want a component using the custom keyboard to be the owner pass it as the "getCustomKeyboard" parameter.